# Request by soap API to send a triggered email it's not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, triggered-send

I'm trying to start a triggered send using Soap in Marketing Cloud. I have the following envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <UsernameToken>
            <Username>myUsername</Username>
            <Password>myPassword</Password>
        </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
            <Client>
                <ID>MyClientID</ID>
            </Client>
            <TriggeredSendDefinition>
                <CustomerKey>MyCustomerKey</CustomerKey>
            </TriggeredSendDefinition>
            <Subscribers>
                <SubscriberKey>angivel@gmail.com</SubscriberKey>
                <EmailAddress>angivel@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>First Name</Name>
                    <Value>Angie</Value>
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>emailaddr</Name>
                    <Value>YW5naXZlbEBnbWFpbC5jb20=</Value>
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>firstname</Name>
                    <Value>QW5naWU=</Value>
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>Lastname</Name>
                    <Value>VmVnYQ==</Value>
                </Attributes>
            </Subscribers>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

When I use this envelope I get the following response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:91854451-19f4-40a3-a89c-41d45d12491f</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:8366b3b7-f7ca-46cc-9c65-d56c12045da9</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-044e7d11-161a-4b60-bd85-6384df7101b3">
            <wsu:Created>2017-05-15T16:03:55Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2017-05-15T16:08:55Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Results xsi:type="TriggeredSendCreateResult">
            <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
            <StatusMessage>Created TriggeredSend</StatusMessage>
            <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
            <NewID>0</NewID>
        </Results>
        <RequestID>51e26102-d87a-4e33-a595-79925a9fe6c7</RequestID>
        <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
    </CreateResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

Which for me means that the triggered send was successfully sended. **BUT** even when I get the OK, and MC says that the email send was "completed" I'm not receiving **anything** in gmail.

I raised a case in salesforce and they say they can't do anything because, for them, Marketing Cloud is sending the email and that the problem is my email server.

Any idea of what can cause the email is "being send" but not ??.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a firewall or any other filtering service on your gmail account? Have you checked your tabs on your gmail account? spam box?

Comment: Hi Gortonington, I was able to find the reason just a moment ago. It seems that the request had an attribute that was an email and we were sending it encoded in base64 and that caused the issue, we removed the attribute and the emails begun to reach their destiny. This kind of issues should raise an error in Marketing Cloud, as the issue is probably inside MC (now we are sending the same email but encoding the email address in a script on the email and they are reaching their destiny so it wasn't a problem on the email service providers as Salesforce said).

Comment: @AngieMilenaVegaLeon : Need a help here. What value did you put for password here? Was it combination of password and secuity token? If yes from where did you get the security token? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request had an attribute that was an email and we were sending it encoded in base64 and that caused the issue. We removed the attribute and the emails begun to reach their destiny. This kind of issues should raise an error in Marketing Cloud, as the issue is probably inside MC (now we are sending the same email but encoding the email address in a script on the email and they are reaching their destiny so it wasn't a problem on the email service providers as Salesforce said).